# Android app badges

Tags: android, badge, android-developer-api

There seems to be a lot of old and confused information about this, so sorry if this is an obvious duplicate - but I see no clear answer for this.

It seems that some common apps on Android devices are able to show badges consistently and with what seems to be native support.
For example Whatsapp and Facebook show badges for unread messages.
Furthermore, **if these apps are in a group, the group gets the badge as well**. Somehow they make it work across different phone manufacturers and os versions (In my experience, at least with LG G3 with Android 4.4.4, and HTC One with Lollipop - **these show the badges differently, suggesting it's something built in and not the app changing icon or activity**)

Please only answer if you a have a clear and certified answer on how this is done and don't answer to say "can't be done" or with some workaround that might work here but not there etc.  - as these answers are not helpful. If big apps like the mentioned use something, I'm sure it isn't some workaround that isn't consistent and might cause problems, but an actual way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

We can implement badge in Android, however there are limitation like, some devices doesn't support it like Nexus, some are supporting as well.
For best solution, you should use [this](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) library. Using it, you can get solution for badge.